# How to join two tables with sequelize MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two existing tables with data where I wanted to join the two tables are show the result by a column value awg and gauge,

Tableone is a master table and Table two is an association

expected output is :

awg,item_des,connector_type

**table 1 :**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../util/dbconnect');

const TableOne= sequelize.define('TableOne', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  awg: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

module.exports = TableOne;

**Table 2:** 

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../util/dbconnect');

const Tabletwo= sequelize.define('Tabletwo', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  item_des: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  gauge:{
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  connector_type:{
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  }

});

module.exports = Tabletwo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without writing raw query. You need to add [associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html) to each of the table definitions.

add below to TableOne

```
TableOne.hasMany(Tabletwo, {foreignKey: 'YOUR_FOREIGNKEY_HERE'})
```

add below to Tabletwo

```
Tabletwo.belongsTo(TableOne, {foreignKey: 'YOUR_FOREIGNKEY_HERE'})
```

you also need to add foreignkey to your tables and then replace **YOUR_FOREIGNKEY_HERE** with the column name.

and then in your code you need to use [.find](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html) with **include**

example below:

```
TableOne.find({ where: { ...}, include: [Tabletwo]})
```

Comment: thanks feiiiiii for the help, do you think the above model would work as im uploading the data manually,
// this is for foreign keys

awg_id:{

type: Sequelize.STRING,

references:{

model: TableOne,

key: 'awg'

}

}